# Remove duplicate records with special rules - Is it possible with a single query?

Tags: mysql, query, duplication

I have the following data in a table:

```
id    loc1    loc2    zip_code
------------------------------
10    1       null    12345
10    null    1       null

11    1       null    null
11    null    1       43210

12    1       null    54321
12    null    1       87654

13    1       null    null
13    null    1       null

14    1       null    65432
15    1       null    null
16    null    1       76767
17    null    1       null
```

The goal is to remove the duplicates with some special rules.

To accomplish this, I have the option to delete the "bad" records directly from my original table or copy the "good" records into a new table.

**Rules:**

- Each record always has one location set. i.e. we either have `loc1` or `loc2` for each row.
- The unique rows (`id: 14-17`) are good as they are
- For the duplicate rows (`id: 10-13`), I want to choose only one row:

  - The row that has a `zip_code`
  - For all other cases, we must always choose the primary location. ie. the one that has `loc1`

After de-duplication, the final data should look like this:

```
id    loc1    loc2    zip_code
------------------------------
10    1       null    12345
11    null    1       43210
12    1       null    54321
13    1       null    null

14    1       null    65432
15    1       null    null
16    null    1       76767
17    null    1       null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY zip_code IS NULL, loc1 IS NULL) rn
              FROM test )
SELECT id, loc1, loc2, zip_code
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

---

> If I want to use this for deleting the duplicates, all I need to do is change WHERE rn = 2. Is that correct? – advncd
>
> @advncd No, MySQL does not support updatable CTE. You must use this query as a subquery which selects rows which must be stored while deleting from another copy of source table.

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM test t1
JOIN (WITH cte AS ( SELECT *,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY zip_code IS NULL, loc1 IS NULL) rn
                    FROM test )
      SELECT id, loc1, loc2, zip_code
      FROM cte
      WHERE rn > 1) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                      AND t1.loc1 <=> t2.loc1
                      AND t1.loc2 <=> t2.loc2
                      AND t1.zip_code <=> t2.zip_code;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9d20c2d27aa3390cec746f8b480a0a8)

Comment: Genious!  After posting the question, I came up with a solution using subqueries but this is much better.

Comment: If I want to use this for deleting the duplicates, all I need to do is change `WHERE rn = 2`. Is that correct?

Comment: @advncd No, MySQL does not support updatable CTE. You must use this query as a subquery which selects rows which must be stored while deleting from another copy of source table.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Using `rn = 2` to create a list of `to_be_deleted`.

Comment: @advncd I'll add the variant shortly, wait... Done. Enjoy!